# Проблемы с переходом на MVP

Tags: android, recyclerview, retrofit, mvp

Есть приложение, которое получает данные с сайта и заполняет ими `RecyclerView`. Хочу перейти на MVP. Прочел множество статей и знаю в теории что это за паттерн. Но не могу применить на практике. Подскажите где ошибся?

MvpView (Глобальный)

```
public interface MvpView {

    void showProgress(boolean visibility);
}
```

ListCatalog (для списка)

```
public interface ListCatalog  extends MvpView {

    void getCategories(MainModel mainModel);

    void getList(Context context, String sortBy, String sortType);
}
```

Presenter

```
public class ListCatalogPresenter extends MvpPresenter<ListCatalog> {
    private MainModel mainModel;

    public void getCategories() {
        String sortBy = "popular",  sortType = "desc";
        MyApp.getHoffApi().getModel(sortBy, sortType).enqueue(new Callback<MainModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MainModel> call, Response<MainModel> response) {
            mainModel = response.body();
            getView().getCategories(mainModel);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MainModel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Адаптер

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder> {
Context context;
MainModel mainModel;

public CategoryAdapter(Context context, MainModel mainModel) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mainModel = mainModel;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new CategoryViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_category_recycler, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.getHolder(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mainModel.getRelatedCategories().size();
}

public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView nameCategory;

    public CategoryViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        nameCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_category);

    }

    public void getHolder(int position) {
        nameCategory.setText(mainModel.getRelatedCategories().get(position).getName());
    }
}
}
```

В MainActivity

```
ListCatalogPresenter presenter;

presenter.getCategories();
```

Ошибка

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.idrisov.hoff.mvp.listcatalog.ListCatalogPresenter.getCategories()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: А что вы понимаете под "где ошибся"?

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka добавил ошибку

Comment: mvp это вчерашний день. mvvm гугл советует использовать

Comment: P.s. По поводу реализации MVP  Лучше не изобретать велосипед, а использовать Moxy. Изучить можно за пару часов...

Comment: @linar спасибо за совет, учту

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не вижу вашего кода в Activity, но из ошибки есть вполне очевидный вывод: *"Вы не создаете экземпляр `ListCatalogPresenter`"*.

Все что вам нужно сделать это создать его экземпляр: можно просто через

```
ListCatalogPresenter presenter = new ListCatalogPresenter();
```

Если вы используете какой-либо DI то можно прописать его зависимость в модуле.

**UPD:**

Для того чтоб `Presenter` знал о существовании вашей `View` вы должны в него положить ее экземпляр. Обычно в `Presenter-е` делается пару методов:

```
public void attach(MvpView view) {
    this.view = view;
}

public void detach() {
    view = null;
}
```

и в самой `View` в `onCreate()`/`onDestroy()` *(хотя тут можно и другие колбеки взять, но важно чтоб они были зеркальны)* вызываются attach/detach.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    presenter.attach(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    presenter.detach();
}
```

Ну и важный момент в том, что до того как вы вызовете attach вы не должны использовать `Presenter` т.к. там будет `view = null`

Вот есть 2 урока на эту тему: [попроще](https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/493-mvp-dlja-nachinajuschih-bez-bibliotek-i-interfejsov.html) и [посложнее](https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/473-mvp-na-primere-jekrana-s-pin-kodom.html).

Comment: После предложенного вами ответа вышла та же ошибка, но в другом месте. В интерфейсе 'ListCatalog'

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Если это не поможет, то хорошо бы видеть код вашей активити, а не те 2 строчки

Comment: Благодарю. Моя ошибка была в том. что я не вызвал метод attachView (он был у меня в презентере)